# Android Studio doesn't trigger functions from main menu bar (MacOS)

Tags: macos, android-studio

I recently updated Android Studio to 3.4.2 (MacBook Pro, MacOS 10.14.6) and realized that functions - when triggered from main menu bar - are not launched. Under normal circumstances I use the keyboard shortcuts and don't need the upper menubar so it is possible that this issue was existing on the previous AS 3.3 which was installed before switching to 3.4.2.

The same issue exists on my iMac (also MacOS 10.14.6). On both machines I reinstalled AS to start with a clean installation. But no change.

I'm really struggling with this issue and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this seems to be an IntelliJ issue on MacOS.

This helped me to continue working: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-434?_ga=2.54265000.1047475875.1566166554-975070946.1566166554&p=IDEA-175658